# Getting involved in an open-source Python-Java project

Tags: java, open-source, python

I'm a first-year PhD student in Ireland. My background is in mathematics, though I'm going to stream my career into programming with Python, Java and C++ languages. I have some good experience with C++ what allowed me to have a presentation in Europe quite recently - I participated in an open-source cloud computing project. I used Python a little bit in this project, though mainly it was in C++.

I was reading a beautiful "Thinking in Java" book this summer while looking for a PhD. I have no experience in Java. I learned some Python while writing a website based on Django.

I love programming languages since my childhood - I started with Pascal and C. Since then I have not been programming all the time of course.

I know some other auxiliary tools like Git, SVN, SQL, XML and javascript. I want to take my concentration in hands and remember design patterns by the way.

Now...

I have earned some money to have food for 2 years. I really want to find a job, but there is no interesting job on the market or my skills are not enough to get one. So I really want to learn Python and Java in parallel by reading books (have already chosen proper ones), searching google (got used to it) and most important writing code and thus I think to participate in an open-source project again.

Could you please list me 2 or 3 projects in Python and/or Java which are currently active (vivid) and useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to be a doomsayer, but I think your question it just too broad.

There are tons [TONS!] of open projects out there that you could participate in. If you want to get involved I would just find something that interests you and hop right in. If you're into game development, find an open game engine to help with. If you're into compilers, find an open compiler project. Do you want to do embedded systems or OS programming? Do you want to help create an IDE or web browser? The key to contribute is finding a project you are excited or care about and charging ahead with it.

Edit:

Here are some open projects that I know off the top of my head

**JAVA:**

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/contribute/)
- [LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

Comment: Hmmm... Then with that in mind I suggest just sitting down and writing a few little applications just to suit a whim of yours. Get the feel for design and proper programming. Then once you feel comfortable hop into a more serious contributory situation.