# High performance and/or real time java open source applications

Tags: java, real-time, high-performance

Which open source java projects do you know to be **high performance** or **real time performance**? I tried hard to find them on github or google, but couldn't find suitable.
I want to learn from this projects, so will not be as a newbie on my interviews ;)
So far I am going to stick to [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) project. 
Are there better options?

P.S. I've seen [possible duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128897/getting-involved-in-an-open-source-python-java-project), but I am looking for a very load intensive applications. As people in Deutsche Bank write.

Comment: Are you looking for specific kinds of high performance projects? and are you wanting to contribute to them or just learn?

Comment: I want to learn, to contribute is the next step. High performance based on the high load at the input and fast processing of the input data.

Comment: Is Hadoop of the high performance kind?

Comment: Florian! Thanks. I missed that Hadoop is open source. That is definitely what I am looking for :)

Comment: LMAX Disruptor is probably the most famous.

Comment: @MartijnVerburg, thanks for the LMAX, it is worth seeing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is extremely performant and open source. https://github.com/apache/cassandra

It's a pretty huge open source project that focuses on high writes, no single point failure and has a good feature set (including distributed, eventually consistent counters).

HBase is another extremely good distributed, noSQL BigData replica. https://github.com/apache/hbase